# Nuxt/Axios _axios.default.post is not a function

Tags: ecmascript-6, axios, nuxt.js

I am getting the following error when trying to do a axios post. Any ideas?

"_axios.default.post is not a function"

My code

```
    import axios from '@nuxtjs/axios'
    const configEng = config[process.env.NODE_ENV]
    export async function getTokenHelper(){
    const res = await axios.post(<url>, null, {params: { grant_type: 'client', client_id: configEnv.client_id, client_secret: configEnv.client_secret}})
   return (res.body.token)
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios', '@nuxtjs/pwa', '@nuxtjs/proxy'],
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  },
  proxy: {
    '/api': { 'target': 'https://localhost:8443', 'secure': true },

    server: {
      host: '0.0.0.0', port: 8443, https: {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(<keylocation>)), cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(<certlocation>)), ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(<calocation>))
      },
    },
  }
}
```

#### More explanation as of my issue

I am attempting to run the code above on the server side in `/api` where all of my node code is written.
It's making the post call to a "3rd party" token tool written by a different division in our company. I do have a `$get` that is calling my `tokenHelper` that sends it back that is existing in my store folder. But the code above is running in my server. It's the only post call I make.

Comment: Hi, please make a minimal effort here and provide more context as of where this code is called. Also, did you followed the setup? https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup Goes a `GET` work btw?

Comment: sorry the code is called in the on the server side of nuxtJS in one of my *.js files that I am having my client call. The GET works on the client, I can't try it on the server because every get I would have to call requires me passing a token which I am getting from this method. Finally yes that is a typo.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how it is called still. DId you followed the setup for the `axios` module?

Comment: Yes, my   modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios']  is set up inside my nuxt.config as is my axios:{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've formatted your `nuxt.config.js` for you.  There are still some warnings there, that you should be aware of, but nothing blocking I guess.

What if you make a `/pages/test.vue` file and try to `POST` on a JSONplaceholder path, like this.

```html
<template>
  <button @click="testAxiosCall">Test the call! </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async testAxiosCall() {
      const result = await this.$axios.$post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
        title: 'foo',
        body: 'bar',
        userId: 1,
      })
      console.log('result', result)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Does it work as expected in the network tab?

Comment: Isn't that using Axios on the client? I am attempting to run the code above on the server side in the /api where all of my node code is written. It's making the post call to a "3rd party" token tool written by a different division in our company. I do have a $get that is calling my tokenHelper that sends it back that is existing in my store folder. But the code above is running in my server. It's the only post call I make.

Meaning it's not in a .vue file, it's in a .js file

Comment: @Jamie in that case, a regular `axios` is enough. https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios It may not be needed to wire it to Nuxt directly.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing. It seems weird that I had to have one axios on the server and one on the client, i thought the purpose of the nuxt/axios version was to be able to use that package across both?

Comment: Depending of the scope of the project, `nuxt/axios` may not be useful. At the end, official documentation suggests `axios` depending on where you do write your code.